# Telerik radrichtextbox goes into readonly mode after printing

Tags: c#, telerik, richtextbox

I have a radrichtextbox that always goes into readonly mode after printing. It seems like a bug to me, as this does not happen as long as I don't print. I am printing in native mode using RadRichTextBox.Print. I even tried setting IsReadonly property to false and that does not work either.

```
Grid rootGrid = element as Grid;

var returnedElements = rootGrid.ChildrenOfType<RadRichTextBox>();
RadRichTextBox richTextBox = returnedElements.FirstOrDefault();
if (richTextBox != null)
{
   richTextBox.Print("TestPrint", PrintMode.Native);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but have you checked the release notes, or known issues for the version of the telerik controls that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way I could work around this issue was to force IsReadonly to false immediately after printing.

Answer (score 0):

The following slight variant seems to be robust with a 4-tab 1 window application:

```
App.Current.Exit += delegate(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(App.ResourceAssembly.Location);
};

App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

I needed to do some stuff when the window closes so just killing the app outright was not helpful in my situation although it did work as advertised.